# A query about Cookies in Servlets

Tags: servlets

```
Cookie usernameCookie = new Cookie ("username", attributeUsername);
usernameCookie.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
response.addCookie(usernameCookie);
```

A cookie is created in the server in this  way and it is added to the HttpServletResponse .

Then why is it that , a HttpServletRequest Header  contain cookies ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are transmitted **per** request, example use case:

1. The first client request does not contain cookies
2. Server sets cookie A, it is transmitted back to the client in HTTP header `Set-Cookie`; this is what `response.addCookie` does.
3. The second client request sends HTTP header `Cookie` containing a list of all matching cookies (including cookie A)

Cookies are part of the HTTP protocol. Wikipedia provides a fine overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie